# How can I duplicate a row in Google Sheets while retaining all of the formulas and format?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need help with Google Sheets. We are using a sheet as a working file and new rows will be added by different users. Formatting and formulas are included in various columns.

How do I ensure the new rows will contain the required formatting and formulas?

Answer (score 0):

to ensure retaining of formulas there is a cell / row / column lockdown future which is invoked by **<kbd>F4</kbd>** right after you type a cell reference. this will add **$** symbols before column and/or row. there are **4** possibilities for how to refer to a cell:

type something into cell **B3** and paste in cell **E1** one of these:

- **`=B3`** (this will refer to **B3** but by adding *row+column it will refer to **C4**)
- **`=$B$3`** (...by adding *row+column it will refer to **B3**)
- **`=$B3`** (...by adding *row+column it will refer to **B4**)
- **`=B$3`** (...by adding *row+column it will refer to **C3**)

*meaning of **row+column** - (adding a row between rows 1 and 2) + (adding a column between column A and B)

---

to ensure formatting to be not broken by inserting row+column you will need to pre-format them with or without using Conditional formatting

---

to ensure formulas will do what it should by inserting row+column you will need to use **`=ArrayFormula()`** which counts for inserting row+column

Comment: Can you expand on how you make sure the formatting isn't broken? For instance, I have a row in which I see one column spanning several columns, but when I try to insert a new row, it doesn't span these columns. (And I don't know what you mean by "pre-format them with or without" which seems to be meaningless if it can be either one)